# Ultra-efficient UTF8 byte encoding in C#

Tags: c#, optimization, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to achieve maximum performance in a library that needs to convert C# strings to byte[] before sending them off somewhere.

Since a char in UTF8 takes maximum 4 bytes, my current approach is to preallocate a large byte[]. When a string arrives for encoding, I can use [System.Text.Encoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoder(v=vs.110).aspx) to populate the byte array with it. If the string's char length * 4 is bigger than my buffer, I allocate a new one (optimizing via a buffer pool), but this is supposed to become relatively rare quite quickly.

My only issue with this solution, is that System.Text.Encoder doesn't appear to accept a string - only a char[]. Retrieving a char[] from the string involves another seemingly needless copy. There's an unsafe version with char pointers, but I'm prohibited from using that in my library at the moment.

As a side note, StringWriter, which also does UTF8 conversion, maintains an internal buffer. This is again unsuitable - I need my own buffer since I encode other data types as well (e.g. ints).

So does anyone have any idea where Encoder doesn't provide a method that works directly on String?

Comment: This questions gives out large vibes of mistargeted optimization attempts. Do you need to reduce storage space (since you choose utf8 instead of utf16/utf32), memory usage (since you worry about copying data) or cpu usage? How large are the strings? Have you done any profiling that states that the serialization is your current primary issue? Can you accept utf16, the inner-storage of a normal string, instead of converting it to utf8?

Comment: I'll give some context - I'm a core contributor at Npgsql, an ADO.NET provider for Postgresql, and we're working on removing needless allocations and copy operations. UTF8 is mandated by my backend (Postgresql). I have no prior knowledge of string length. Each connection can (and should) hold an internal buffer for conversions and encoding of this sort. I'm trying to avoid both needless copying, and especially to make the encoding process as zero-copy as possible.

Comment: Note: created a request for this overload on Microsoft Connect: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6584398-add-system-text-encoder-convert-method-string-in

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the [Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx) classes, they wrap the Encoder classes.

It sounds like you should stick with the builtin text encodings until they have been proven ineffective. There's a [UTF8Encoding.GetBytes(String, Int32, Int32, Byte[], Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsy6z64h(v=vs.110).aspx) which will take your string and write directly to your pre-allocated byte array.

There's also a [UTF8Encoding.GetByteCount(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6s9akh92(v=vs.110).aspx) that can calculate the size of the byte array before you allocate memory for it.

Comment: Thanks! I somehow missed this particular overload of GetBytes(), concentrating on the encoder instead! This method is exactly what I need. Note that GetByteCount() implies going over the string and doing double processing, I'd rather simply be pessimistic, assume 4 bytes per char, and skip that step.

Comment: Worst-case can be calculated using the GetMaxByteCount-method. It seems to return 3*(charCount+1) which implies that the builtin utf8-encoding will never generate more than 3 bytes per character.

Comment: That doesn't seem true - UTF8 really can generate 4 bytes for a single character in certain (extreme cases). The docs at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.utf8encoding(v=vs.110).aspx say this quite explicitly.  But the suggestion to use GetMaxByteCount() rather than calculate myself is indeed a good one, thanks.

Comment: @Shay reference source code of System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetMaxByteCount (see http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/utf8encoding.cs) really seems to return 3*(charCount+1) where the formula is commented as "_Max 3 bytes per char.  (4 bytes per 2 chars for surrogates)_" - whatever it means :)

Comment: Thanks @xmojmr. That's strange, I know UTF sometimes encode to 4 chars, but frankly I'm not that fascinated by the whole thing to dig deeper. I'll put my trust in GetMaxByteCount()...

Comment: @SimonSvensson and others, there's one issue with UTF8Encoding.GetBytes(String, Int32, Int32, Byte[], Int32): it's unsuitable for chunked encoding (in case you have a fixed buffer for network I/O, which is my case). In other words, if the string I have is bigger than my buffer, I can't use this function to encode it across two different buffers. Compare this with Encoder.Convert(Char[], Int32, Int32, Byte[], Int32, Int32, Boolean, Int32, Int32, Boolean), which allows exactly this, but which... accepts only Char[]. I guess I've returned to my original question...

Comment: @Shay, isn't this solved by checking if the array is large enough with GetByteCount before calling GetBytes?

Comment: @SimonSvensson, GetByteCount() informs me the string is too large for my array. But what do I do then? I don't want to allocate a new array, I'd rather encode what I can to the array (part of the string), write that to the socket, and so on. Encoder.Convert allows this (unlike UTF8Encoding.GetBytes), but it accepts only a char[] as input... I hope the problem is clear...

Comment: Just reduce charCount until you get a value that fits inside your buffer (according to GetByteCount) and then call GetBytes with that. You could probably build something less naive by trying to guesstimate a better charCount that just retrying charCount-- all the time.

Comment: @Shay: 4 bytes are required for astral characters, but C# uses UTF-16 internally, so astral characters take up two `char`s, giving 2 bytes per `char`

Comment: @SimonSvensson, your suggestion is a good approximation even if not very easy to implement - strictly speaking I have no way to reduce charCount to match my buffer since I don't know how many bytes will be required (without again calling GetByteCount()). In any case there is no solution - I basically need an Encoder.Convert() that accepts a string (see the Microsoft Connect issue I opened, comment to the original question). Flagging this question as answered.

Comment: UTF-8 can use up to 4 bytes for a single Unicode code-point, but in the 4-byte case the code-point must be a surrogate pair in UTF-16, i.e. 2 `char`s in .NET, so 3*charCount is safe.